# Refactor ruby helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a helper method which checks whether the collection of objects is empty? If not then it checks each one to make sure that the the existing event_id is not the @current_event.id.

Here is my crack at it:

```
def build_answers(question)
  if question.answers.empty?
    return question.answers.build
  else
    question.answers.each do |a|
      if a.event_id != @current_event.id
        return question.answers.build
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Update: This helper method sets the form to build new children objects if the conditions pass. I've updated the example above. btw, it doesn't need to be a single line. I just wanted something cleaner than what I have above.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what actions are performed in the blocks marked 'logic'?

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? `question.answers.build` shouldn't be inside that `each` block, and there's no point calling `question.answers.build` if the collection is empty..

Comment: Actually that is what it is supposed to be. I didn't want to put down all the other code because the form is really complex but it actually works as expected. Thanks for your answer below.

Comment: At first glance, this looks like it ought to be a method of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you're actually doing inside the blocks, it's difficult to give the best solution.

For the most part, all you could really do is [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003125) before executing the logic on the filtered collection, rather than testing the logic in the block.

e.g.

```
uncurrent_answers = questions.answers.select{|a| a.event_id != @current_event.id}
uncurrent_answers.each do |a|
  #do whatever
end
```

IMHO it's a little bit neater, and perhaps more rubyish..

Comment: The select block is what I was looking for (I didn't know what it was called). map and other methods just didn't work (obviously). Thanks!

Comment: @Nate For future reference, you might want to check out all the other methods that are in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know why would you want to put conditions into a single line, but the else block could be rewritten into this:

```
question.answers.select {|answer| answer.event_id != @current_event.id }.each
    {|ans| #.. logic with answer here }
```

Comment: I gave you a point for coming up with the select option first. Just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you current method is responsible for too many things, my idea is to create a clase with a single responsibility of building answers. That would make your code more readable and also easy to test. A posible implementation would look something like :

```
def build_answers(question)
  AnswerBuilder.build(question.answers, @current_event)
end

class AnswerBuilder
  def initialize(answers, current_event)
    @answers = answers
    @current_event = current_event
  end

  def self.build(answers, current_event)
    new(answers, current_event).build
  end

  def build
    if answers.empty?
      answers.build
    else
      create_allowed_answers
    else
  end

  private
  attr_reader :answers, :current_event

  def create_allowed_answers
    answers.each do |a|
      if a.event_id != current_event.id
        return answers.build
      end
    end
  end
end
```